# Always On: could a slow replication connection affect the client overall performance?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, synchronous, alwayson

I have read in this blog article:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/alwayson-data-synchronization-in-synchronous-and-asynchronous-mode

the following:

*If the secondary replica is configured to run in synchronous mode, it will send an acknowledgement on the commit to the primary node indicating that it has hardened the transaction, and so it is safe to tell the user that the transaction is committed. And because the log has been hardened on the secondary, there is a guarantee that in case there is a failover, there’s no data loss.*

As I understand it, if the replication connection between both replicas suffers some kind of delay (perhaps due to a poor bandwith), the same delays will affect the client which issued the transaction in being notified its  transactions are commted.

And this could affect the client overall performance since the client must wait for receiving one transaction commit before it issues the next one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The client will wait until the log record is hardened on synchronous secondary replica(s). Replication latency will affect the client performance accordingly.